# Albacore msbuild task problem

Tags: ruby, rake, albacore

Just updated albacore to version 0.14 and ran into a major problem.

My current environment is:

- **Ruby** 1.9.1
- **Rake** 0.8.7
- **Albacore** 0.1.4

The problem is that as of **now** all my rake build throw a funny little exception:

```
undefined method 'push' for #<Enumerator:0x???????>
```

So far I have traced the problem to albacore msbuild.rb line 38 and 26.

To be honest I just don't have a clue why this is happening. As a little help here is the rake task that is turning my hear Grey :)

```
desc "Build solution"
msbuild :build => :prepareOutput do |msb| 
  msb.properties :configuration => :Release
  msb.targets :Clean, :Build
  msb.solution = "../xxx/xxx/xxx.sln"
end
```

Comment: Ran into the same problem my self. So just want to "bump" the question.

Comment: crap... thought i had that fixed before the 0.1.4 release... I'll get this fixed ASAP and have a new build out tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just pushed albacore v0.1.5 up to rubygems.org, which has everything working correctly - except ssh and sftp - for ruby v1.9.1 now.

the ssh and sftp gems that we are using have not been updated to support ruby 1.9.1. hopefully they will be updated at some point. until then... everything except for those two tasks should work.

Answer (score 0):

After one day of fidling around and not finding the right answer. I reluctantly had to revert back to albacore version 0.1.3.

Because there is no revert functionality in the **gem** specifications I did it with a simple uninstall and install :)

```
gem uninstall albacore -v 0.1.4
gem install albacore -v 0.1.3
```

I know that this not a real solution, so if anybody has a better idea please respond.